# How to retain text when saving as PDF?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, pdf, export

I am having an issue when I attempt to save as PDF from Adobe Illustrator. For some reason, only a portion of my text is saving to the PDF document. I have locked all my layers, which I was under the impression would allow me to preserve them during export. I believe the issue has something to do with overprint (apologies as I am new to Ai). I've included a few screenshots to hopefully help diagnose the issue.

[[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: This post seems not only unclear, but literally incomplete. I ***strongly*** suggest an edit to complete the thought and explain what user has tried, where this failed, and screengrabs to illustrate said states.

Comment: Do you own the font you want to use? If the font is copy protected, you will have trouble using it. If you do not have the font, you may have to convert the text to outlines and embed them as artwork rather than text.

Comment: Hi Stan, yes we own the font. I also have created outlines for all the text. For some reason, only a portion of this text is appearing, however (will add photos).

Comment: Select the white text elements and ensure Overprint isn't ticked on the **Attributes Panel**.